# Is there any significance to the vomiting zombies in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

In the original Dying Light on the PC, at certain times in the game you will see zombies apparently vomit at random.

This isn't in relation to anything that you as the player do (for example, using a toxic crossbow bolt), or anything environmental that I'm aware of.

Is this simply a random sequence to add flavor to the game, or is there any gameplay significance to it?

Comment: Apart from vomiting being used as a death animation (which you are clearly not talking about), there are vomiting zombies, that shoot toxic projectiles at you. I take it you don't mean those either? Are they simply vomiting unto the ground? And can you tell which zombie type(s) do(es) this?

Comment: Just normal grunt zombies stopping and vomiting. From what I can tell it only applies when they're in a default state, not when they are alert or when they are attacking. It looks like a random behavior, but I'm not sure if I missed something.